How to implement dynamic icons in web push notifications on iOS?
I'm working on implementing web push notifications for my webapp (pwa), and I would like to display dynamic icons in the notification based on realtime data from my api on iOS devices. I would like to know if there are any workarounds or methods for achieving this behavior on iOS through web push notifications.
i have tried implementing web push notification and it works fine but the icon in the notification is getting replaced by the icon specified in the manifest.json file.
here is my script
async function run() {
  console.log('run called');
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    console.log('Service Worker supported');

    const button = document.getElementById("subscribe");
    button.addEventListener("click", async () => {

    const result = await window.Notification.requestPermission();
    console.log(result);
    if (result === "granted") {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register(
        "service-worker.js"
      ).then((registration) => {
          console.log(registration);
        // 
          var url = '(api_call)';
          fetch(url)
            .then(r => r.json()
              .then(data => ({
                status: r.status,
                body: data
              }))
            )
            .then(obj1 => {
              if (obj1.body != null) {
                var obj = obj1.body;
                
                registration.showNotification(obj.title, {
                  lang: 'en-US',
                  body: obj.desc,
                  icon: obj.icon, 
                 }).then((output) => {
                  console.log('notified', output);
                }).catch((error) => {
                  console.log('showNotification error', error);
                })
              } else {
                console.log('no data', obj1.body);
              }
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('service worker registration failed', error);
        });
    } else {
      console.log('Notification permission denied');
      alert('Please enable notifications');
    }
    });
  } else {
    console.warn('Service Worker not supported');
  }
}

run();

So, the icon passed in showNotification gets replaced by icon i have mentioned in manifest.json.
manifest.json
{
  "name": "TestNotification",
  "short_name": "Notification",
  "display": "browser",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "theme_color": "#db4938",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "test1.png",
      "sizes": "48x48",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}

service-worker.js
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
  event.notification.close(); // Close the notification
  event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url));
});

